# Command line inputs as arguments

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am designing a program for a class and one of the instructions is to use command line inputs. For example when you run `main -n 5 3` it is taking in `5` and `3` as arguments. What is `-n`?

How can I test this on a PC with codeblocks instead of a linux machine?
How would my program read these in?
Do I need to name my file main and then in the main have two arguments that get passed in appropriately?

Comment: `-n` is `argv[1]`, `5` is `argv[2]` and `3` is `argv[3]`

Comment: I don't understand what -n is suppose to represent in my program then, I only need two arguments, the 5 and 3.

Comment: Did you write this program yourself? If so, then you get to choose what `-n` means, and if it accepted at all. You can always print an error message and abort the program when you find unexpected arguments.

Comment: The confusion is that I only need two variables. The document describing it says that the -n is somehow related to the first number argument.

Answer (score 4):

Your `main` function in your program has the prototype

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv);
```

Where `argc` will contain the amount of arguments passed and `argv` is a pointer to an array of `char*` that contain your arguments as null-terminated strings.

Usually `argv[0]` contains the name of your program, `argv[1]` your first argument and so on. In your case when you run your program with the arguments `-n 5 3` you will have

```
argv[1] = "-n"
argv[2] = "5"
argv[3] = "3"
```

Comment: That makes sense, so I can access the array to assign those integers to be used in my program. Is this something I can test on windows?

Comment: @PaulthePirate Yes, but keep in mind that they come as strings. You will need to convert them to integers with `atoi` or similar function first. Try printing your arguments with: `int i; for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) printf("%s\n", argv[i]);`

Comment: @luiscubal you can not have type declarations in a for loop in C, that's a C++ extension.

Comment: @SergeyL. I'm pretty sure it's valid C99 and, in fact, I suspect even in C89 it works -- it just has the "wrong" scope, though GCC seems to show an error. Either way, here is another way to write the same thing: http://pastebin.com/TFK5uTmb

Comment: Is  int n = atoi(argv[1]);  valid?

Comment: @PaulthePirate It should work. Just make sure to check that `argc >= 2`, or else you'll get a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

> a.exe -n 5 3

results in the following content of `argv`:

`argv[0]` = `a.exe`
`argv[1]` = `-n`
`argv[2]` = `5`
`argv[3]` = `3`
`argv[4]` = `NULL`

and `argc` will be `4`.

---

On linux, there's an [`getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) function in `unistd.h` that might help you to retrieve `n` option and parse arguments that follow. Howevef if your program just needs to find `-n` and read the value from the two arguments that follow, you could do:

```
int i, x = 0, y = 0;
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-n") == 0 && i + 2 < argc) {
        x = atoi(argv[i+1]);
        y = atoi(argv[i+2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have linux so I can't really test it, but my files need to work on linux so I want to do as much testing before I move to linux.

Comment: @PaulthePirate: I've updated my answer + added some additional info :)

Comment: Would int n = atoi(argv[1]);
     char* address = argv[2]; work? Assuming a string for the last input

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Yes it would. Although you might want `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` (not 1 and 2 because 1 is `-n`)

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the parameters are in argv[...].  In the real world, many people use something like [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) to parse the parameters as it is very robust and already tested.

Answer (score 1):

Usually C uses argc and argv to allow you to index the arguments passed from the command line. I have not worked on a PC for a while but when I did the code was consistent with Unix.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("Total args count=%s\n", argc);
  printf("Command=%s\n", argv[0]);

  for (i=1; i< argc; i++) {
    printf("\narg%d=%s", i, argv[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This would return

```
Total Args 4
Command main 
  1 = -n 
  2 = 5 
  3 = 3
```